# What is the point of your "faction"?

Tags: titanfall-2

In TitanFall 2, I've unlocked one or two extra "factions" in multiplayer. They are each led by various characters from the campaign, but other than a lore description of what each faction represents, I can't really figure out what the point is.

What do you gain by joining a particular faction?

Answer (score 9):

[Some players said](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/134596-titanfall-2/74486533?jumpto=6) that leveling up factions unlock unique items for your emblem.  They also point out that you'll have different voice announcers in the game. [A second thread](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/titanfall/comments/5a5rx4/titanfall_2_anyone_know_what_factions_do/?client=ms-android-att-us) said the same things.

[This site](https://www.google.com/amp/www.gameskinny.com/google-amp/nmn6l/titanfall-2-multiplayer-guide?client=ms-android-att-us) states:

> Leveling up factions will [grant] callsign rewards. You can switch factions as you level and unlock more.

These rewards are banners and patches for your emblem. Besides that, it doesn't seem like there is much more to factions.  In the first link I've included someone also stated that you're more likely to be teamed up with people in the same faction.

Comment: @StrixVaria was this too speculation to warrant an accept or did it just slip by you? :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no point except the various Personality a of the leaders
there is no gameplay effect but it is fun to hear your leader of choice wether that be following the cold and calculated orders of the IMC or rallying behind the 6-4 it's only really physcological but it's pretty cool

Comment: Or just here mvrns happy gurgling